# Übersetzung von Doppel "to" in "to make this question harder to get correctly"

Tags: translation, english-to-german, infinitive

> To make this exam question harder for the students to get correctly, I've added a few words.

Wie kann man diesen Satz ins Deutsche übersetzen?

> Um diese Prüfungsfrage schwieriger für die Studenten richtig zu beantworten zu machen habe ich ein paar Worte hinzugefügt.

Ist die Doppelverwendung von **zu** in Ordnung, oder soll man das umschreiben?

Comment: Lass das "zu machen" weg: Um diese Frage leichter zu verstehen habe ich ein paar Worte hinzugefügt.

Comment: @tkausl Da ändert sich deutlich die Bedeutung des Satzes.

Comment: Naja, der Sinn ist der gleiche, aber sowas wie "Um die Frage verständlicher zu machen habe ich ein paar Worte hinzugefügt." würde auch gehen, klingt nur ein wenig komisch.

Comment: @tkausl Vielen Dank für Deine Kommentare. Ich bin trotzdem neugierig auf die Situation mit zwei "zu", und habe die Frage leicht verändert. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Wie kann man diesen Satz ins Deutsche übersetzen?**

Meine Empfehlung ist, `to make` nicht wörtlich zu übersetzen. Es kommt im Englischen deutlich häufiger vor als `machen`im Deutschen, weil es in einigen idiomatischen Wendungen eine bestimmte Funktion übernimmt, ohne daß es wirklich auf das *machen* als Tätigkeit ankommt. Vergleiche z. B. "made of (steel, wood …)", das man einfach mit "aus (Stahl, Holz …)" übersetzen kann. Im vorliegenden Fall geht es darum, eine Zielsetzung auszudrücken, und dafür würde ich die Passivkonstruktion "damit es … wird" verwenden:

> Damit es für die Schüler/Studenten schwieriger wird, diese Prüfungsfrage richtig zu beantworten, habe ich ein paar Wörter hinzugefügt.

**Ist die Doppelverwendung von zu in Ordnung, oder soll man das umschreiben?**

Das hat Loong schon recht gut beantwortet. Im allgemeinen geht das grammatikalisch in Ordnung, ist aber stilistisch meist nicht schön. Dein Vorschlag hat aber dazu das Manko (neben dem fehlenden Komma vor "habe"), daß die Wortstellung falsch ist. Wenn schon, müßte es heißen (wie auch schon von Loong vorgeschlagen):

> Um diese Prüfungsfrage für die Studenten schwieriger zu beantworten zu machen, …

Answer (score 4):

Die Konstruktion mit zwei Infinitiven mit zu ist grundsätzlich möglich, wie man vielleicht besser beim Vergleich der Infinitivgruppe „um diese Prüfungsfrage […] zu machen“ mit dem entsprechenden Hauptsatz „Diese Prüfungsfrage ist […].“ sieht:

> Diese Prüfungsfrage ist schwierig.
> Diese Prüfungsfrage ist schwer zu beantworten.
> Diese Prüfungsfrage ist für die Studenten schwer zu beantworten.
> Diese Prüfungsfrage ist für die Studenten schwerer zu beantworten.
>
> Um diese Prüfungsfrage schwierig zu machen, …
> Um diese Prüfungsfrage schwer zu beantworten zu machen, …
> Um diese Prüfungsfrage für die Studenten schwer zu beantworten zu machen, …
> Um diese Prüfungsfrage für die Studenten schwerer zu beantworten zu machen, …

Allerdings wird in *Duden – Richtiges und gutes Deutsch* darauf hingewiesen, dass das Nebeneinander von mehreren Infinitiven mit zu, die voneinander abhängen, schnell zu sehr komplexen Konstruktionen führt und aus stilistischen Gründen wie aus Gründen der Deutlichkeit vermieden werden sollte.

Answer (score 3):

Das Grundkorsett des Satzes, möglichst eng am Original geführt, würde ich so übersetzen, noch ohne das zweite `to` im `to get correctly`:

> Um die Examensfrage für die Studenten schwieriger zu machen, fügte
>   ich ein paar Wörter hinzu.

Die geschmeidigste Ergänzung wäre hier eine Einfügung vor `Examensfrage`:

> Um die *richtige Beantwortung der* Examensfrage für die Studenten
>   schwieriger zu machen, fügte ich ein paar Wörter hinzu.

*Richtig zu verstehen* oder *richtig hinzubekommen* wären zwar mögliche, fast wörtliche Übersetzungen der Phrase mit `to` zu `zu`, aber in den Satzbau fügen sie sich so nicht ein.